# How to reclaim disk space in InnoDB after dropping table

Tags: mysql, innodb, diskspace

I have a big `InnoDB` table in mysql. The problem is my disk space is almost full. I want to reduce my disk space. If I'll delete some rows from the table and use this command:

```
optimize TABLE_NAME
```

then my disk space will be reduced. But I want to drop the table. If I'll drop the table, there is not any table to optimize it! What is the appropriate command to reduce disk space after dropping the `InnoDB` table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

drop command will free disk space automatically.

Note: Assuming you are using innodb_file_per_table as you are able to free space by optimize table syntax.

Comment: But if you did not create your tables with file_per_table, you have a big problem.  It includes dumping the data and reloading it.  See lots of posts on how to shrink ibdata1.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to configure your server to use [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html), but do make it sure that you have your backup and then drop and restore it. You can run the `optimize table`.

You can run to check if the innodb_file_per_table is ON

```
mysql> show variables like "innodb_file_per_table";
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| innodb_file_per_table | ON    |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually to reclaim space after dropping tables in MySQL you should enable **Per-Table File** in the MySQL configuration. Read more here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: If you did not have `innodb_file_per_table = ON` _before_ doing `OPTIMIZE` or `DROP`, it will not release the freed space to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

**`OPTIMIZE TABLE`** makes a copy of the table.  More specifically it does

1. Create a new table schema like the existing one.
2. Copy the rows into the new table.
3. Rename to swap tables.
4. Drop the old table.

Note especially that for a brief time you will have two copies of the table occupying space on disk.

- If you are too tight on disk space, this will fail.
- If you have `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`, the `ibdata` file may expand, but not shrink.  Again, this may lead to a failure.

Beginning with 5.6.17, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will perform the work in place.  However, you must drop and re-add any `FULLTEXT` indexes.

**`DROP TABLE`** works in one of these ways:

- `innodb_file_per_table = OFF`:  free up space in `ibdata`.  But this space is not released to the OS.  Instead, it will be reused for inserts, etc, to any table.
- `innodb_file_per_table = ON`:  The file taken by the table is promptly released to the OS.

But...  When I refer to the setting of `innodb_file_per_table`, I am referring to the setting when the table was `CREATEd` or last `ALTERed`, not the current setting.